# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null | discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a message tracker and this error shows and I don't know why

**Code: messagecounter.js**

```
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
    name: "msgc",
    description: "Message Counter",

    async run(client, message, args) {

        // checking who wants to fetch it
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member; // this checks if they mentioned a members

        db.fetch(`messageSent_${member.id}`).then(obj => {

            message.channel.send(`**Messages Sent:** \`${obj.value}\``);

        });
    }

}
```

**Code: bot.js:70:42**

```
client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);
```

**Error:**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\blade\commands\messagecounter.js:13:45)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\blade\bot.js:70:42)
```

Any help would be appreciated

**Using discord.js v12**

Answer (score 1):

After quickly glancing over "quick.db" I couldn't find a method called fetch defined on the db object. "get", however is defined and is perhaps what you meant to use.

Comment: According to the docs for quick.db, none of the methods returns a Promise. The get method returns an object, which in your case turns out to be null. This might mean that the object being queried doesn't exist.

Comment: here is the link to the docs: https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs